# Cannot read property 'length' of null error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm very new to javascript and I am trying to implement an UI where charts are generated in a chatbot-like webpage. The whole project can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/6cfL8f3b/#&togetherjs=xP8EBTR8SH

Using Chart.js for every press of the enter knob, the function below will then create a new chart.

```
function drawChart(){
  $('<canvas id="chart"'+j+' class="chart"></canvas>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');
  a = String('chart'+j);
  console.log(a);
  new Chart(document.getElementById(a), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Population (millions)",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
            data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
        }
      }
  });
  j++;
}
```

The null property lentgh error occurs at new `Chart(document.getElementById(a)`

Using a normal id, this works perfectly but the goal is to generate multiple charts.
Could someone point me out the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: So, does `document.getElementById(a)` exist?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById(a))`... Looking at your use of an possibly undeclared variable, `j`, I wouldn't be surprised if that was the problem.

Comment: Just rechecked j is declared but console.log(document.getElementById(a)) returns null. Which I don't understand because it is created a couple of lines earlier

Comment: so, what does `console.log(a);` say?

Comment: console.log(a) returns chart1, thank you for helping btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in here:

```
 $('<canvas id="chart"'+j+' class="chart"></canvas>')
 //                  ^
```

Replace that with:

```
 $('<canvas id="chart'+j+'" class="chart"></canvas>')
 //                       ^
```

You closed the `id` attribute before `j`.